# How to fix jquery ajax not sending data to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a system similar to a like/dislike system. I have it all setup, but my jquery.ajax function is not sending the data I need it to. The function is being called, but the data is not being set.

I've added a function to check for if the isset if statement is being called, but that function isn't being called, so I know it's something wrong with the ajax function. I've tried looking over other posts of similar problems, but none of those solutions worked. Sorry if this is just me being stupid, and the solution is easy.

PHP - community.php - The main webpage

```
<div id="entries">
    <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <div class="entry">
      <div class="entryInfo">
        <img src="IMAGES/PlaceholderAlbumCover.jpg" alt="Album Cover" class="center" height="200" width="200">
        <div class="artistInfo">
          <h4><?php echo $post['name'] ?></h4>
          <p> <?php echo $post['artist'] ?> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="votes">

          <i <?php if(userVoted($post['id'])): ?>
              class="fas fa-heart vote-btn"
            <?php else: ?>
              class="far fa-heart vote-btn"
            <?php endif ?>
            data-id="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>" style="color:#f44242">
          </i>

          <span class="voteCount"><?php echo getVotes($post['id']); ?></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>

  </div>
```

Javascript - vote.js - Handles click detection and sending the response to vote.php

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?page=community',
      method:'post',
      data: {
        'action':action,
        'post_id':post_id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if(action == 'unvote') {
          $click_btn.toggleClass('far fas');
        } else if(action == 'vote') {
          $click_btn.toggleClass('far fas');
        }
      }
    });
```

PHP - vote.php - Handles the server side of the system

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    consoleLog();

    $post_id = $_POST['id'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    switch($action) {
      case 'vote':
        $query="INSERT INTO rating_info (user_id, post_id, rating_action)
                VALUES ($user_id, $post_id, 'vote')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rating_action='vote'";
        break;
      case 'unvote':
        $query="DELETE FROM rating_info WHERE user_id=$user_id AND post_id=$post_id";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
    echo getRating($post_id);
    exit(0);
  }
```

What it's supposed to do is increment or decrement the vote count in the mysql database by setting the action to vote or unvote, but the js file just never sets the action data, or the PHP script is never able to catch it.

Comment: where did you call the function to run the ajax

Comment: I called the ajax function from the javascript, just using the jquery '.on("click", function() {' method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the post data in the javascript as `post_id` but trying to retrieve it in the php script as `$_POST['id']`

Do this instead: `$_POST['post_id']`

Comment: I changed that, but there was no visible change in what happens. That probably would have given me an error if the if statement actually executed, so that saved me from that later, but the main problem still stands.

Comment: Are you sure the file php file is what is being called? confirm that is the correct route you specified in the ajax call

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you. I should be able to figure everything else out.